# X configuration, dpms in one of two monitors

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I am using lubuntu 18.04 64bit with a radeon hd4650 video card and I'm using a monitor on vga and a tv on hdmi.
I am trying to set dpms settings only for the vga monitor, I did some searches around and came up with this solution: create a 10-monitor.conf file to put in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ with the following text

```
Section "Monitor"

Identifier   "Monitor0"

Option          "DPMS"

EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"

Option "StandbyTime" "1" 

Option "SuspendTime" "30"

Option "OffTime" "40"
```

I have set a low standbytime so it's easier to check if it works or not. At the moment it works with both the monitors, but I only want it to work for the first one.
any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many times and didn't get any result, but in the end I know it's impossible thanks to the x.org mailing list